# On a Youtube-like website, would it make sense to use individual sqlite files to store video comments? (One sqlite file per video.)

Tags: sqlite

"On a Youtube-like website, would it make sense to use individual sqlite files to store video comments?  (One sqlite file per video.)"

I'm curious to hear what anyone thinks.

Comment: I don't think SQLite handles high-volume, multi-user stuff very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've stated in the comments that you already have a MySQL database for videos, there's little sense in using SQLite for commenting. A comments table with a video_id column is going to be a lot more flexible.

SQLite also doesn't hold up too well in a situation where you might have concurrent writes, which commenting is.

Comment: Would it make any more sense to use sqlite tables for "thumbs up" or "like" functionality?  i.e. - A user "likes" the video, and this contributes to the total number of "likes."  I'd need to keep track of "likes" so that a single user can only "like" a video once.

Comment: It'd be helpful to know why you're so focused on SQLite. My answer applies to likes for the same reasons it applies to comments - write-heavy, concurrent users, you have MySQL already.

Comment: Reasons why I'm interested in sqlite: (1)I've never used it before, so I thought it might offer some kind of advantage that I hadn't considered.  (2)I thought it might make remote site backups easier.  (3)I thought that reading from a bunch of small databases would be faster than sorting through one potentially huge database.

Comment: You're presumably already having to back up MySQL. Sure, there'll be more data in it, but if it becomes a concern down the line (if your site gets enormous and popular) you can replicate to a slave MySQL box for backing up without touching the live database. As for sorting, that's what indexes are for.

Comment: I'm convinced!  Thank you, ceejayoz, and everyone else, for all of your help!

Answer (score 2):

The reopening of so many files and file handles at the OS level may cause a performance hit. I would let the database do what databases do best and just have a FK to the video ID for each comment.

Comment: Are you sure that opening one file handle per pageview would be too much to handle?  The reason why I asked this question is because I was hoping to have an easier-to-backup setup.  I was hoping that it would be easier to backup a bunch of sqlite files than to (far in the future) backup a huge table of tons and tons of comments.  I also thought that sqlite file options would lead to really fast comment retrieval, since each sqlite db would be named something like this: [video_id]_comments.sqlite.  So instead of grabbing all comments with video_id = 5, I'd just go to 5_comments.sqlite.

Comment: I'm sure if you were to do a performance comparison. Opening a file and reading all entries into it vs. having an index on the FK to video ID. The FK option would be faster. An intelligent database engine may even cache the index table to allow for faster searching options. Also out of curiosity how would it be easier to backup many small files vs one large one. Knowing how file systems work I would imaging backing up one large one rather than many small ones would be faster.

Comment: I definitely agree that backing up one large file would be faster than backing up a lot of small ones, but how does backing up a bunch of small files compare to using phpMyAdmin to create a text-based backup of mySQL insert statements?  (I have no idea what the answer is.)  I'm thinking both about the backup speed and how that kind of backup would affect the site's availability to users while the backup was occurring.

Comment: I guess I'm getting a little confused. First you were mentioning SQLlite now you're talking about mySQL. I also would just like to comment that if you are that concerned about backup, performance, and availability, I'm guessing this may be a high volume (concurrent writes) website. If it needs to be that reliable with that great of up time I would definitely not use SQLLite as a more enterprise database engine (MySQL) will have much better backup tools for incremental backups.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I'll clarify.  I'm currently using mySQL, but I was wondering if it would be worth supporting comments through the use of sqlite instead.  That was where my sqlite questions came from.  For me, my options were either (1) Use a single mySQL database, or (2) Use a bunch of small sqlite databases.  It wasn't actually a question of whether a single sqlite database would be better than a whole bunch of sqlite databases.  And after all of this, I definitely agree that mySQL would be a much better option.

Comment: Ok in that case I would just stick with MySQL and use incremental backup for quicker backups, also these can be done live with no down time.

Answer (score 0):

It would make it impossible (or very difficult) to efficiently search all comments.

Comment: Fortunately, I only need to display comments in this case.  I wouldn't ever need to search through them.

Comment: @hithere Never say never. @SLaks This should've been a comment, though.

Comment: @Hithere: **Yet**.  @Ceejayoz: Why? It answers the question.  (Don't)

Comment: @ceejayoz @SLaks In this case, I'm definitely certain that I won't be doing any searching.  I only want to do things like, "get comments 1-10" or "get comments 110-120."

Comment: Then how will you search videos?

Comment: And what happens when every video on your site gets hit by a comment spammer and you want a quick query to find all of his comments?

Comment: @SLaks The video data will be indexed in a separate mysql database.  I'm only talking about storing *video comments* in each single sqlite file.  (One sqlite file per associated video.)

Comment: @ceejayoz My plan was to store: comment_id, user_id, comment_text in a table in the sqlite file.  If someone spammed the site, I'd just delete all comments by the user with that user_id.

Comment: Sure, but you'd have to go through each video's SQLite database to do so. Seems rather silly if you've already got a MySQL database for other stuff.

Comment: @ceejayoz Hmm...yeah, I see what you mean.  My major incentive was to avoid having to do backups from a large remote database (I thought that a bunch of self-contained files would be easier), but the sqlite setup might not be so good of a solution after all.